# Calculadora jQuery concatena en vez de sumar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo una calculadora con jQuery y Bootstrap pero no me está sumando bien, en este caso solo contenido jQuery que es donde está el problema. Lo demás funciona perfectamente, pero en los cálculos no va bien, tengo el siguiente código:

```
var total = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#boton_igual").click(function() {
    //if ($("#resultado").val().trim().length != 0) {
    $("#resultado").val(total);
    //}
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#boton_sumar").click(function() {
    if ($("#resultado").val().trim().length > 0) {
      total += parseInt($("#resultado").val());
      $("#resultado").val('');
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#boton_borrar").click(function() {
    $("#resultado").val('');
    total = '';
  });
});
```

Primero estoy probando con la suma pero no se porque la suma me lo hace mal.

Comment: Hola! @josanangel , igual deberias dejar el html junto con el jquery como ejecutable , así sería más fácil ayudarte ya que no sabemos como es tu calculadora.Y otra cosa por que tantos document ready?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "no está sumando bien" y "en los cálculos no va bien"? ¿Qué es lo que hace mal exactamente?

Comment: Hola josanangel, ¿qué es lo que está haciendo mal: no hace nada, recibes el resultado incorrecto, aparecen decimales raros, aparece algún error en la consola...? Además, deberías añadir el HTML como te indican en el otro comentario.

Answer (score 0):

En el botón borrar estas inicalizando total como un string, despues de borrar la suma empieza a concatenar los números, debes inicializar total a 0

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#boton_borrar").click(function() {
  $("#resultado").val('');
  total = 0;
  });
});
```